# I am almost everything

Tags: riddle, haiku

> I know everything
> But I like to be stupid
> Almost in your hand
>
> Creator of worlds
> I am almost everything
> I'm under your nose

What am I?

Comment: I'm tempted to answer "Me" :p

Comment: @QuestionAsker No, it's You!

Comment: Its Aurelion Sol. Done. Gimmie meaningless rep.

Comment: @Daedric Who's Aurelion Sol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it

> Internet

I know everything

> Internet know everything

But I like be stupid

> Can not do anything unless we ask him to do as in search for anything

Creator of the worlds

> Refers to World Wide Web

I am almost everything

> Refers to the fact it is used everywhere. House Controls , monitoring , education, medical it is used everywhere

Almost in your hand

> We have internet in our hands using phones, tablets

Comment: You did it! YAY!! (But you need to explain more...)

Comment: Google seems to be dumb... Hint Hint!

Comment: com on your so close you should no wat i mean by "I like to be stupid" by reedin' dis post (And also, the explanation of "Creator of worlds is slightly wrong.)

Comment: @You  updated the answer hopefully it's correct

Comment: @LearningPhase "I like to be stupid" and "Creator of worlds" still have the wrong explanations. It's more about the people than the actual thing...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am a

> keyboard on a computer

I know everything

> everything gets typed through a keyboard

But I like to be stupid

> but like a teenage school student won't actaully do anything unless you stand over it and make it work

Almost in your hand

> well, directly under your hands, in fact

Creator of worlds

> the great creative work of authors comes from typing through the keyboard

I am almost everything

> what don't we do on the using computer and keyboard, these days?

I'm under your nose

> literally, as you sit and type

Comment: Close. The answer uses a keyboard...

Comment: The same response would fit for both a computer and typewriter.....

Comment: It's not a computer...

Comment: may I edit my answer for typewriter?

Comment: Not a typewriter either. Or anything with a keyboard.

Comment: So it "uses a keyboard" but the answer "isn't anything with a keyboard"...